# AMP image with text inside

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Who can I show an image with text inside using AMP?

Something that looks like this, but on AMP

html:

```
<div class="backgroud-image">
  <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
```

css:

```
.backgroud-image {
  background-image: url("image.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can use background images with AMP. Are you encountering an issue?

Comment: It looks like it really works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Coker said, you can use background images with AMP (as referred to your example). You may check on this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/EE6vLjfm-f8).

> You can add styling in the head element with the style amp-custom element. One possible problem is that in AMP the images are supposed to have their size declared in the code, but with a background image you declare with styling directives the size of the element containing the image, not of the image itself.

You can check on this [blog](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11288077) for more information.